# How to wait for a AngularFire2 subscription to finish before running the next lines of code Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have a problem with my Angular2 Type Script code. I'm trying to access Questions from a Firebase Database, which I am doing by subscribing to a FirebaseListObserver:

```
this.af.list('/questions').subscribe( val => {
     this.questions = val
     console.log(this.questions) // works
})
console.log(this.questions) // displays undefined
```

I dont know how to wait for the subscription to get a value, though, before running a function which depends on `this.questions`.

I tried to use async/await, but also didn't wait for the subscription to get a value.

I also tried to subscribe inside a promise, but also returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run the function from within the `subscribe` callback or you can turn `questions` into a setter/getter:

```
private _questions = [];

set questions(questions) {
  this._questions = questions;

  // React to questions changes here
}

get questions() {
 return this._questions;
}
```

Which will act kinda like a watcher if you're familiar with the early version of angular. So in the `set` function you can check if `questions` has a value and react to it, calling whatever function you need.

Comment: I already tried to call the function in the subscribe callback, but it seems to work inconsistent, so sometimes it works, but sometimes it returns undefined. I have the same problem with the setter/getter.

Comment: @LucasMähn That shouldn't happen, can you add a `.filter(data => data !== undefined)` before the subscribe and see if that helps?