# How to use map instead of Subscription in Angularfire2, Ionic 3

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, angularfire2

In my project, I am using Ionic 3 and AngularFire2. I have to get the value from firebase database and to do some changes and display it in HTML page so that I have to wait for subscription to complete. Here is my code:

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {}

async ionViewDidEnter(){

  var a = await this.calldatabase(); 
  console.log(a);       // it display first and value is undefined
  console.log('3');     // it display second
}

async calldatabase(){

  let category: any;
  this.items = this.afDB.list('/cat', { preserveSnapshot: true });
  await this.items.subscribe(snapshots => {
     snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());      // it displays third
        category = snapshot.val();
     });
  });
  return category;
}
```

`

I can't make wait for subscription to complete, then I googled it and then found these links

[angularfire2 wait for subscription to end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253713/angularfire2-wait-for-subscription-to-end)

[Angular 2 Wait for subscription to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162905/angular-2-wait-for-subscription-to-complete)

[How to wait for a AngularFire2 subscription to finish before running the next lines of code Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143850/how-to-wait-for-a-angularfire2-subscription-to-finish-before-running-the-next-li)

Can't able to resolve. Now Im trying to use map instead of subscription it doesn't display anything

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

async calldatabase(){

  let category: any;
  this.items = this.afDB.list('/cat', { preserveSnapshot: true });
  await this.items.map(snapshots => {
    console.log(snapshots);              // it displays nothing

    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.val());      // it displays nothing
      category = snapshot.val();
    });
  });
  return category;
 }
```

[My Cat value in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuD0R.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afDB.list('/cat', { preserveSnapshot: true });
```

This is an Observable where you can Subscribe on.

```
async calldatabase(){


  return this.afDB.list('/cat', { preserveSnapshot: true });

 }
```

Then you can use this statement in the component where you need the data

```
showMyData(){

this.callDatabase.subscribe((data)=>{
//Do something with this data
console.log(data)});

}
```

I suggest that you use a service for Firebase and a model for the Cat.
The you can use the following code:

```
showMyData(){

let theCats: Cats[];

this.callDatabase.subscribe((data)=>{
theCats = data;
console.log(theCats)});

//Do something with theCats
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can post the code that you have until now.